# Initialize array by range

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way in Typescript I can initialize an array with values from n to m without naming all elements?

What I use today:

```
let lst : number [] = [5,6,7,8];
```

What I am looking for:

```
let lst : number [] = [5 .. 8];
```

Comment: No, you should create an utility function for it.

Comment: (Because no, there's no TypeScript-specific syntax for that.)

Comment: As far as I see, the question has not been answered by the posted threat. The answer-threat is about creating an array from 1 ... N, the question was from n ... m.

Comment: But also there is still an answer in the threat: Array.from({length: 10}, (_ , i) => i + 1) 10 and 1 are your variables here, 10 being the length you want and 1 the value of the first element. So for your example: let lst: number[] = Array.from({length: 4}, (_ , i) => i + 5)